# How to properly create a bin using mockbin API?

Tags: php, api, rest, http, mocking

I'm trying to create a bin using [mockbin API](http://mockbin.org/docs#create-bin). I tried [PHP/cUrl](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/b27aefbe7321f3d0f3e9), SoapUI and Postman, but I keep getting empty response body:

Request:

```
POST /bin/create/view HTTP/1.1
Host: mockbin.org
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 12 Jan 2016 13:21:50 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d183c7edefea549cc0bbe219ac11fe7c81452604909; expires=Wed, 11-Jan-17 13:21:49 GMT; path=/; domain=.mockbin.org; HttpOnly
Vary: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Accept, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: host,connection,accept-encoding,x-forwarded-for,cf-ray,x-forwarded-proto,cf-visitor,content-type,accept,user-agent,via,cf-connecting-ip,x-request-id,x-forwarded-port,connect-time,x-request-start,total-route-time,content-length
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Encoding: gzip
Via: 1.1 vegur
Server: cloudflare-nginx
CF-RAY: 26392aae22092ac1-WAW
```

Expected response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Location: http://mockbin.org/3c149e20-bc9c-4c68-8614-048e6023a108
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 38

"3c149e20-bc9c-4c68-8614-048e6023a108"
```

Other API methods work correctly, i.e. [echo](http://mockbin.org/docs#echo).

Comment: Are you sending any data along with your POST request?

Comment: No, as it is not required. I have tried with some data taken from mockbin API docs, but that did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an error in the mockbin API docs. I have installed it locally and checked sent request when creating mockbin using html form. It seems the [proper request is](https://github.com/Mashape/mockbin/commit/b957248bd30056e7ecf76c6f5f60cb031a2f3f08#diff-f2b6dc1109937688451038d8dbc1c5cd):

```
POST /bin/create HTTP/1.1
Host: mockbin.com
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

response=%7B%22status%22%3A200%2C%22statusText%22%3A%22OK%22%2C%22httpVersion%22%3A%22HTTP%2F1.1%22%2C%22headers%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22cookies%22%3A%5B%5D%2C%22content%22%3A%7B%22mimeType%22%3A%22text%2Fplain%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D
```

Comment: It looks like docs site has not been updated for a long time. I will try to contact mockbin team and ask for update.

Comment: author of mockbin here, thanks for pointing this out! will fix the docs immediately.